# Looking for Technical Information on a Gadget with Fall Detection and Reporting Capability

Tags: hiking, safety, gear, united-states, solo-hiking

I am old enough to plan ahead on fall detection, but vigorous and stable enough not to need it in everyday life now.  However, I no longer feel comfortable hiking alone, and would like a gadget that would detect a fall and report it, preferably where there is no cell signal;  **this may be too much to ask for but it is vital to know if it can or can't.**

I originally thought about the Apple watch, but it can't be the **only** such gadget -- or can it?  (The pendants one wears around one's neck are too hideous for any word but UGH!)  I am not interested in any function except fall detection and reporting.  I don't hike to be in touch with the world.  I have a beautiful watch for time-keeping.  So, techies, please don't regale me about all the neat stuff such a gadget can do. Thanks! (To clarify:  I don't mind paying for a function that tells me the hourly temperature in Madagasgar; I just want never to be aware of it.)

One other point:  I have a narrow wrist, and even something the size of the small Apple watch looks clunky and out-of-place on my wrist.  I would like to wear the Gadget about halfway between my wrist and elbow, so it will be decently concealed by long sleeves.  **Vital** **technical requirement:** The gadget should work reliably in this position.

Please Note:  I am **not** asking about price.  I **don't care** if something better is coming down the pike.  I am asking about what is available with the above specs **now**.  So, all the rationales about  shopping questions do not apply.  I am asking for pure technical information that will inform a near-term decision.

Comment: Re *the pendants one wears around one's neck are too hideous*, and *I have a narrow wrist*. Why can't you keep it in a pocket, where it is out of sight?

Comment: as a side note, the apple watch cannot report where there is no cell signal, in case that was not obvious

Comment: Interesting question - you might be better off asking/migrating to the Medical Stack, though that's pretty small and personal medical questions are off-topic. I don't see that asking if such a device is available would be personal medical advice though. I'll ask on their meta and see.

Comment: Terrible idea. First, it would have to be a satellite phone to work outside of cell coverage, and second it would have to have a way of cancelling false alarms. And what happens when you unknowingly drop it 20 miles into the wilderness and it sets off an alarm? The SAR team that shows up hours later after an expensive, dangerous rescue effort to find nothing is not going to be happy. You should expect a huge bill for that service and deservedly so.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that it needs to be fully automatic? Are you expecting that _if_ you fall you will be so badly hurt that you won't be able to manually raise an alarm? Otherwise, a PLB would be an option. They're still a bit bulky, but you can carry it in a pocket or at your belt.

Comment: @PMF no, it does not have to be fully automatic.  And njzk2 told me that the Apple needs cell reception to notify, so the Apple is not useful for hiking.  I agree on the PLB.

Comment: Yes, I know some extraordinarily clumsy people. Their name is the public. I spent 15 years in EMS and I guarantee that the device you seek will generate false alerts and will result in unnecessary SAR responses. Do you understand how expensive and dangerous SAR responses can be? I won't be surprised when some jurisdictions start refusing to respond to alerts from such devices.

Comment: Your device can fall out of a pocket. Does such a thing ever happen unnoticed? Of course it does. You know that 'stuff happens' or you would not want to carry it in the first place.

Comment: There's no reason for hostility. I just think the device you want is a bad idea and I explained why.

Comment: Thanks to @njzk2  who actually answered the points in the question.

Comment: @PMF Thanks for a answering the question.  I have decided to follow your advice.   I was never keen on the Apple Watch, njzk2 delivered the kiss of death to that idea, and you provided an alternative, which I knew about but had overlooked.

Comment: Yes, a 406 MHz PLB/ELT is vital *anytime* you go off well-trafficked roads - so many tragedies have happened *even in cars* where someone gets confused and goes deeper into desert/backwoods and gets stuck.  And it needs to be a "single use, tear the shrinkwrap off it and push the button" type ELT, not a "tinker-toy for tweeting" like a SPoT that also advertises ELT as a sidecar feature, that use the sat-phone networks which give inferior coverage to the 406 system.  That's the mil-spec gold standard, used by jetliners and container ships.

Comment: @ab2: as it turns out, the newest apple phones can now talk to satellites: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213426 It has some limitations to be aware of, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend a 406 MHz PLB (Personal locator beacon) which uses the COSPAS-SARSAT system. Details are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_position-indicating_radiobeacon). In short: A PLB (or EPIRB, or ELT, they're all technically equivalent) is a small device that sends an alert with a position using a satellite network. It works worldwide (even at the poles, or far offshore) as long as there's clear view to the sky.

PLBs are the smallest devices of this group, about the size of an old Nokia cell phone. They are activated simply by the push of a button. Downside is that they don't allow sending any information about the nature of the distress. On the Pro side is that they do not require any subscription (only a registration, but that is - in most countries at least - free) and that they do not require any user servicing. The battery is built-in and lasts for at least 5 years, after which it needs to be replaced by the vendor.

Comment: Devices such as Garmin InReach do support two-way text message communication via satellite (requires a monthly subscription).  And the newly released iPhone 14 also supports emergency communication via satellite.

Comment: @BrunoRijsman I haven't heard of that. If you can source it,  maybe write an answer?

Comment: InReach is technically a "satellite messenger", an entirely different technology that allows messaging but requires a subscription.

Comment: The iPhone 14 is interesting, but note that the announcement seems to be that the **first 2 years** of sat comm will be free.  Leaving entirely open what, if anything, it will cost past that.  I also would not confuse a PLBs extreme robustness,  battery longevity and suitability for its only job with being 110% sure my cell phone would replace it when my life depended on it.  But it is something to consider on the iPhone lineup, for sure.

Comment: You should clarify that your answer refers to a genuine 406 MHz ELT/PLB, which uses the global satellite system made *specifically* for emergency location. This is the gold standard for aircraft and serious ships e.g. tankers and container ships.  The emergency beacons on naval ships that pop off when they sink, those use 406. Not a SPoT. Not an iPhone.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica isn't this clear? I even linked to the Wikipedia page about these devices. Suggest an improvement, please.

Comment: @PMF I didn't think so, hence my comment. At your request, improvement submitted.  Please do not rely on content of links for substantive parts of your answer; links can go stale leaving the answer incomplete.  Quote or summarize what is said in the links in your answer.

Comment: While this is a good answer note that it does not have fall detection!  As stowed in my pack my PLB isn't even capable of operation--the antenna must be unwrapped first.

Comment: @LorenPechtel The OP confirmed that manual activation was acceptable, for the reasons mentioned in the comments of the question (fall detection has a high probability of a false alarm). A PLB should be carried where it's immediately reachable, e. g. at the belt or in a coat pocket.

Answer (score 2):

The PLB that PMF is referring to is a good answer.  I will also mention the inReach units, though--while they likewise do not have fall detection they can be set to periodically transmit your location to the satellites.  If you're hurt badly enough that you can't activate it it still is very likely to be able to lead search and rescue right to you when you're reported overdue.

I do not know if SPOT and the other similar devices have this capability or not.